# Issue with Permissions for Google Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When one of my firebase cloud functions is triggered (cloud firestore trigger), I get a permissions error. I am unsure how to resolve this issue and there are few relevant resources. I have included the function itself as well as the error below.

I have tried reinitializing the app, disabling and reenabling the api, and deleting and redeploying the functions.

Function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import {reportError} from "../logging";
import {chargeTypes} from "../constants/constants";
import {handleCreateTeam} from "./create-team";
import {handleJoinTeam} from "./join-team";
import {handleAcceptInvite} from "./accept-invite";

export async function handleNewJoinTeamDocument(event: 
admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot, context: functions.EventContext, db: 
admin.firestore.Firestore) {
    const todo = event.data();
    if (todo === undefined) {
        return reportError("Todo returned no data in handle new join team document", {user: context.params.id});
    }
    if (todo.processed) {
        return {message: "Already processed this queue item"}
    }
    let result;
    switch (todo.type) {
        case chargeTypes.ACCEPT_INVITE:
            result = handleAcceptInvite(todo, event, context, db);
            break;
        case chargeTypes.CREATE_TEAM:
            result = handleCreateTeam(todo, event, context, db);
            break;
        case chargeTypes.JOIN_TEAM:
            result = handleJoinTeam(todo, event, context, db);
            break;
        default:
            break
    }
    return await result;
}
```

Error:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission at 
Object.exports.createStatusError 
(/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15) at 
Object.onReceiveStatus 
(/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1204:28) at 
InterceptingListener._callNext 
(/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42) at 
InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus 
(/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8) at 
callback 
(/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24)
```

Log Details:

```
{
    insertId:  "000000-b7bc9521-25b8-4357-9301-a5c1df269ef4"  
    labels: {
        execution_id:  "767010698187131"   
    }
    logName:  "projects/snowballtesting-d70da/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
    receiveTimestamp:  "2019-09-29T16:38:47.207554787Z"  
    resource: {
       labels: {…}   
       type:  "cloud_function"   
    }
    severity:  "ERROR"  
    textPayload:  "Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
at Object.exports.createStatusError (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1204:28)
at InterceptingListener._callNext (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
at callback (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24)"  
 timestamp:  "2019-09-29T16:38:45.946Z"  
 trace:  "projects/snowballtesting-d70da/traces/daf59e0d15388a1c4500bb4a88a7a084"  
}
```

Comment: This code looks imcomplete.  I don't see where you use firebase-functions to define a function trigger.  What exactly are you doing up until the time of the error?  Please be specific, so that anyone can follow the steps that reproduces the problem.